Bad smell in bathroom cupboard at 55 degrees
I live in a mobile home in Missouri. Every fall, when it dips below 55 degrees, when I open the cupboard under my bathroom sink it smells really bad. I think this may be underneath the mobile home, but why at 55 degrees and below?? No smell from the drain. This started a few years ago and I have just put up with it every year. When it goes above 55 degrees the smell stops! Any ideas on the problem?

what else happens in your home when the outside temperature drops below 55 degrees?

Take everything out from under the sink. Absolutely everything. Wait an hour, then see if the smell is still there.  If not it is coming from something you stored there.  If it's still there it is probably something under the home. You will need to get under the home and take a look, and a sniff.

Yes, I have done that... the smell is coming up from the water lines underneath my mobile home. Thank you that is what I figured that I would have to hire someone to get under there and check it out, Thank you!

Jsotla... I use my furnace which is right next to the this problem.
